# How to properly add acronyms to CustomDictionary.xml

Tags: visual-studio, fxcop

One of my classes has a public property named `Ttl`. This is supposed to follow the [CA1709](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx) rules:

> By convention, two-letter acronyms use all uppercase letters, and
>   **acronyms of three or more characters use Pascal casing**. The following
>   examples use this naming convention: 'DB', 'CR', 'Cpa', and 'Ecma'.
>   The following examples violate the convention: 'Io', 'XML', and 'DoD',
>   and for nonparameter names, 'xp' and 'cpl'.

Now, code analysis complains about my property, telling me it violates [CA1704](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx) (bad spelling).

I tried adding it to my CustomDictionary.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CodeAnalysisDictionary.xsd">

  <!-- Some unimportant elements are here in the real file -->

  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>Ttl</Acronym>    <!--Time To Live-->
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>

</Dictionary>
```

I tried putting lower, upper and camel case into the dictionary, but none of them will remove the spelling complaint. Is there a way to add this acronym to the XML or do I just have to suppress the message for my properly named property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added "Ttl" as a casing exception. In fact it's *not*. It's three letters in Pascal case.

What you did not do is add "Ttl" as a word.

```
<Words>
     <Recognized>
        <Word>Ttl</Word>
```

Make sure you need it at all. Most .NET languages have "no abbreviations" as a good naming convention.

Comment: The class is a wrapper around a Socket which has a Ttl property so I'd rather not change the name. So in your opinion, I should probably just suppress for this exceptional case, right?

Comment: Accepted the answer since it *is* the right answer to my original question, though. :)

Comment: Personally, I would name it `TimeToLive`. Building a wrapper is no reason to end up with a non-.NET naming convention. I would expect a wrapper to come with the conventions it's wrapping *to*.